# Tuleap - Cardwall not available

Tags: configuration, tuleap

We have installed an instance of Tuleap V7.3.99.11 for evaluation purposes. After creating a project and adding a tracker from the "Tasks" default template, I am trying to add a Cardwall to the report.

Tuleap offers only the options "Table" and "Charts" when adding a new tab to the report. The online demo offers "Cardwall" as a third option (https://demo-tuleap.enalean.com/plugins/tracker/?report=586&renderer=1225).

How can I add a Cardwall? Are there any dependencies not fulfilled by a fresh standard installation?

Update: I have found the installation instructions for the Agile Dashboard (https://tuleap.net/doc/en/user-guide/agile-dashboard.html). I did not find any references to a Cardwall plugin by itself.
I executed the installation, there were no errors and several trackers appeared in the project (Epics, Releases, Sprints, Tasks, User Stories). But there still is no option to add a Cardwall tab. (Also no Agile Dashboard entry in the sidebar)

Update2: I executed "yum install tuleap-plugin-cardwall" and the installation was confirmed as successful

> Installed:
>     tuleap-plugin-cardwall.noarch 0:1.35-1
>   Complete!

But in the project, there still is no Cardwall option. I tried removing all trackers and executing the Dashboard installation again, to no effect. Trackers are created, Cardwall is not offered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more of a SuperUser question than stackoverflow. You need to install and activate the cardwall plugin.

yum install tuleap-plugin-cardwall

[Update]

The plugin then needs to be activated as Site Administrator in the "plugin management" section of the main platform Administration section.